# Into_account not run properly in polkadot-v0.9.24

Tags: bug

[image]

No method named `into_account` found for struct `PalletId` in the current scope. Although I added AccountIdConversion traits. This issue happen when I update polkadot version from 0.9.20 to 0.9.24. I used environment:
rustc 1.62.0 (a8314ef7d 2022-06-27)
cargo 1.62.0 (a748cf5a3 2022-06-08)

Answer (score 3):

The old `into_account` function was ambiguous and possibly dangerous in certain cases.
You can now use `into_account_truncating` instead.

The function does exactly the same thing as before, but its name was changed to indicate that it is possibly truncating some of the seed data.
This is important in the case that you passed a very long seed and expect the returned account to depend on the full seed.

The change happend [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10719) together with the introduction of `try_into_account` and some other functions.